# How to make translations for NgbDatepicker in Angular without subclassing NgbDatepickerI18n?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-i18n, ngb-datepicker

I am currently reading about internationalization of the `ng-bootstrap` components. Their documentation says for the datepicker:

> Since the 2.0.0 release datepicker will use the application locale if
>   it is present to get translations of weekdays and month names. The
>   internal service that does translation is called NgbDatepickerI18n and
>   you could provide your own implementation if necessary.

[(ng-bootstrap website)](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#i18n)

Looking at the Angular i18n documentation, it states:

> If you want to import locale data for other languages, you can do it
>   manually:
>
> **src/app/app.module.ts**
>
> ```
> import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
> import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
>
> // the second parameter 'fr' is optional
> registerLocaleData(localeFr, 'fr');
> ```

[(Angular website)](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

But why is it not working for me? Do I still have to make a custom implementation of `NgbDatepickerI18n`, or am I missing something?

---

**Here is an example playground:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mezpyn?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.module.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and becuase there's no answer, this is the solution:

After importing and registering the locale data as you did, in app.module.ts you need to add

```
providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' },
    ... other providers
],
```

The documentation doesn't make it clear in my opinion.

Comment: I wish I can upvote this more than one time. Finally someone who know how to change the language with using the I18n data.

Comment: Where `LOCALE_ID` is imported from `@angular/core`. I just noticed this answer now, thank you!

Comment: do you have a working example for that? In the stackblitz above the days are still in english.

Comment: @user2622344 refer to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mezpyn-b6tm1r?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.html for a working sample

Comment: I've done this as you said like this { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' },
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-EN' },
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'nl-NL' } but datepicker is only using the last provider I declare (nl) and is not reacting to application language change. What am I missing?